# Tensorflow Serving with image input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to send image input over http to classify using tensorflow. I have looked in detail in the c++ code for https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

I have implemented the inception-v3 example model using C++ API. It takes image input in the following form:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image --image=my_image.png
```

However, I want to add the case of:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image --image=http://www.somewebsite.com/my_image.png
```

This is due to the fact that it only accepts local image files. I want to add the functionality to take file pointers from online images and classify it in memory. I'm currently working on this, but so far no luck. Can anyone offer some insight how I would go about implementing this?